# How to make a multiple word dog name count as one token

Tags: java, arraylist, split, token

My code takes each word from a line and separates them into Tokens by spaces. There should only be 6 categories of tokens on each line if there is any more or less an Error would print.The problem is when there are dogs with a space between their name like German Shepard. My code counts it as an error. 
If the Dog name German Shepard I want my code to count it as one token like "German Shepard".

```
ArrayList<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();
int numLine= 0;
while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {

    // read a line from the input file via sc into line
        line = sc.nextLine();
        numLine++;
        String[] fields =line.split("\\s+");
        if(fields.length != 6) 
        {
       System.out.println(line);
       System.out.println("ERROR ON LINE #"+numLine+
       ":number of fields on line must be 6, not "+ fields.length);
       System.out.println();
        }
         // got from Dr. Koch email infromation 


        try{
        StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(line);
        String name = stk.nextToken();
        String breed = stk.nextToken();
        int month = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());
        int day = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());
        int year = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());
        double weight = Double.parseDouble(stk.nextToken());

        Dog list = new Dog(name, breed, month, day, year, weight);


        dogs.add(list);





        }

        catch(Exception missError)
        {


        }

    }
     // close the file
sc.close();
```

Comment: You are doing split on ' ', its a bad idea to delimit your data with just ' ' you should use '|' or ';'.

Answer (score 0):

Before checking for no. of words in a line, Use regex and concatenate tokens.

Like,

```
String pattern = "([A-Z][a-z]+)(\s)([A-Z][a-z]+)";
line = line.replaceAll(pattern, "$1_$3");
```

Then split the line by space and check for the number of words, say 6 or whatever number you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-think how you tokenize your line.  If whitespace is valid in a value, such as your German Shepherd example, you **cannot** use whitespace as your delimiter.  You could follow Gonza's suggestion of using '|' or ';', provided these will not appear in your values (unlikely, based on your description).  Personally, when reading from a file, I tend to go with a unicode character that is untypable, such as an upper case Omega - "\u03A9".

Another option would be to surround all the values with double quotes, like so:

"Fido" "German Shepherd" "01" "01" "2014" "40"

You could then extract the values using a regular expression.  Something along the following lines:

```
public String[] getDogRecord(String fieldList)
{
  final int DOG_FIELD_COUNT = 6;
  final String DOG_FIELD_REGEX = "\"([^\"]+)\"\\s*";
  final Pattern FIELD_PTTRN = Pattern.compile(DOG_FIELD_REGEX);

  int fieldCount = 0;
  Matcher fieldMatcher = FIELD_PTTRN.matcher(fieldList);
  String[] dogRecord = new String[DOG_FIELD_COUNT];

  // First, check we have the right number of fields
  if (!fieldList.matches("(" + DOG_FIELD_REGEX + "){" + DOG_FIELD_COUNT + "}"))
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Incorrect number of fields in record!");

  // Read each field into an array
  while (fieldMatcher.find())
  {
    dogRecord[fieldCount] = fieldList.substring(fieldMatcher.start(1),
                                                fieldMatcher.end(1));
    fieldCount++;
  }

  return dogRecord;
}
```

You would of course need to parse the appropriate array entries when creating your Dog object.  Alternatively, you could modify the above to return a Dog object directly.